# Can't get url. Request 404

Tags: python, python-requests

I am trying to build a simple Python script that parses a web page. I wrote the following code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url)
    print(r)

def main():
#https://hh.ru/search/vacancy?st=searchVacancy&text=data&items_on_page=50  
    get_html('https://hh.ru/search/vacancy?clusters=true&enable_snippets=true&salary=&st=searchVacancy&text=data')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

It works on different urls, but I cannot access this particular one. Can you explain what is the problem there ?

Comment: Some websites restrict crawlers. You can change the request headers to manipulate that but make sure it is legally allowed to do that on their website.

Comment: In fact, if I set Python to use a Chrome user-agent header (e.g. with a value from https://www.whatismybrowser.com/guides/the-latest-user-agent/chrome) I get a 200 response.